# How to insert the data into mongoDB collection manually

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I want to insert the data into Robo3T manually. I tried using insert and insertMany command, but nothing works for me. Please provide me the solution if it's possible.

Comment: Please use https://nosqlbooster.com/downloads

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getCollection('YourCollectionName').insert({"name" : "ABC"})
```